# Convert dataframe row into string of values without column indexes in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe row and want to get it as a string of just the values, no columns.

```
col1 | col2 | col3
-----------------
1    | 2    | 3
x    | y    | z
```

I'd like to be able to select just one row and have it as a string like:

```
'1','2','3'
```

But I keep getting the column names still in there, or lots of other values like:

```
"['1' '2'\n '3']"
```

Comment: Are you willing for a string like `"'1','2','3'"` or `"1,2,3"` would do for you?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

just use

```
df.iloc[1,:].to_string(header=False, index=False)
```

1. header = False --> don't include column names in the output string
2. index = False --> don't include row index in the output string

Answer (score 3):

You can use `iloc` which takes an index and provides the results. `iloc[row_indexes, column_indexes]`

So `df.iloc[0,:]` would take the first (0th) row, and all the columns. It'll pass back a Series, so you can use list comprehension [str(x) for x in iterable] to pass back the values as strings.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2], 'b':[3, 4], 'c':[5, 6]})

[str(x) for x in df.iloc[0,:]]

['1', '3', '5']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a string of the values within row `0` concatenated with `,` you can do as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,"x"],"col2":[2,"y"],"col3":[3,"z"]})
l = df.iloc[0,:].apply(str).values
s = ",".join(l)
```

The list would look like:

```
>> print l
['1' '2' '3']
```

And the string you get is:

```
>> print s
1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.apply(lambda x: list(x), 1)
```